# Drupal, how to create a Custom content type with modular fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

New to Drupal. Figured out how to create custom content types. But am having a hard time figuring out how to customise the content type to have modular fields.

So i have an *article* type. The layout of article is not fixed. The editor should allow the admin to add for eg, full bleed image, or a 2 column image or 1 col text, 2 col text or 3 col text and arrange the sequence as required.

Would appreciate help pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module provide that flexibility.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it out and it looks like it's close to what i want. Any chance you would know how i can add specific css classes to each paragraph bundle types?

Comment: The same way as you add classes to any Drupal element (when it is build with a good template). By implementing a preprocess function and adding your classes to $variables['classes_array'].
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/setting-up-variables-for-use-in-a-template-preprocess-and